# Extending a functional

Tags: functional-analysis

Here's a question I have from an old exam without solutions. I was wondering if you could check my work (and help on part b)

Suppose $g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and $\int_1^\infty |g(x)|^3 \; dx < \infty$. Define for $f \in C_c(\mathbb{R})$ the following functional: $\phi(f) = \int_1^\infty f(x)g(x) \; dx$.

(a) For what $p \in [1,\infty)$ can we always extend $\phi$ to a bounded linear functional on $L^p(\mathbb{R})$?

(b) Repeat (a) if $g$ is also bounded.

My attempt: Hanh-Banach seems to be the solution. Note $(C_c(\mathbb{R}), \| \cdot \|_{L^p(\mathbb{R})} )$ is a dense linear subspace of $(L^p(\mathbb{R}), \| \cdot \|_{L^p(\mathbb{R})})$ for $1 \le p < \infty$. To invoke Hanh-Banach, we need to check when $\phi$ is bounded (w.r.t. $\| \cdot \|_{L^p(\mathbb{R})})$.

Now, since $[1,\infty)$ not compact, there is no inclusions/nestings with $L^p$ spaces. That is, $g \in L^3([1,\infty))$ does not imply $g \in L^p([1,\infty))$ for $p>3$ or $p<3$. For example, if $p>3$ I can take $g(x) = \chi_{[1,2]} \dfrac{1}{(x-1)^{1/p}} \in L^3([1,\infty)) \setminus L^p ([1,\infty))$ and if $p<3$ I can take $g(x) = \dfrac{1}{x^{1/p}} \in L^3([1,\infty)) \setminus L^p ([1,\infty))$.

Say $\left( \int_1^\infty |g(x)|^3 \; dx \right)^{1/3} = M$. Since $f \in C_c(\mathbb{R})$, we know $\int_1^\infty |f(x)|^p \; dx < \infty$ for any $p$.

So I believe we can only be assured of boundedness when $p=3/2$ from Holder's Inequality:
$$
| \phi(f)| \le \left( \int_1^\infty |f(x)|^{3/2} \; dx \right)^{2/3} \left( \int_1^\infty |g(x)|^3 \; dx \right)^{1/3} \le M \|f\|_{L^{3/2}(\mathbb{R})}
$$

Now for part (b), we have $|g(x)| \le C$ for all $x$. Certainly $p=3/2$ from part (a) is still valid, and $L^1$ now is OK:
$$
| \phi(f)| \le C  \int_1^\infty |f(x)| \; dx \le C \| f \|_{L^1(\mathbb{R})}
$$

But now one of my counterexamples fails since $g(x)$ is bounded. I believe $\left( \int_1^\infty |g(x)|^p \; dx \right)^{1/p}< \infty$ for all $p > 3$ now work since the boundedness controls blowup, but I can't think of a formal way to prove this.
Thanks for the help.